# field dos not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a `FutureBuilder` but the result of the code gives me `Bad state: field dos not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform` error.

I searched around before posting this question and found that this error occurs when the "fields" like `users` and `username` are not present in firestore but they are clearly present in my firestore. There is a collection named `users` containing documents with 'uid' as their name. And every doc contains a property `username` in it.

Following is the code of the `FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("users")
                  .where(
                    "username",
                    isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchController.text,
                  )
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                }

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]["photoUrl"],
                        ),
                        radius: 16,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]["username"],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
                );
              },
            ),
```

**Code Explanation:** The `Appbar` contains a `TextFormField` with a controller `searchConroller` which will pass the text to future builder in the body section of scaffold. The `FutureBuilder` will return a `ListView` which will have `ListTile` with appropriate `username` and `photoUrl`(profile picture) taken from snapshot which we will get from the future.

Why is this error occurring then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, The error is really self-explanatory. The fields I was trying to access were all present but I misspelled them and wasted a lot of time reading Firestore Docs and waiting for someone to answer to this question.

Better practice would be (what I can think of): Write down all of your fields in a text file and then write down the fields you are trying to access and compare them, I am sure you will find the discrepancy.

In my case I was trying to access `photoUrl` while the field name was `photoURL`...

Lesson well-learnt.